# Why can't I see/debug javascript loaded with jquery.html() with Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, debugging, google-chrome

I'am loading html with some inline javascript on a $.post callback. Something "like that" :-)

```
callback{
response_data = '<p>string with html and </p><script "javascript">var scripts...</script>'
jQuery('#selector').html(response_data);
}
```

But when I do that, I can't see the new inline javascript loaded on Chrome's Scripts Tab. I see that JS on Network tab and js is executing but I can't debug this code.

Any idea about how to debug this code? Thanks!

Comment: have a look at `Console tab`, right click and select check XMLHTTPRequest

Comment: Because i suppose browsers do not listen to asynchronous calls to update the list of avaiable files

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All modern JS engines do allow to generate a javascript break-point "in-code".

To do that, you need to execute the `debugger;` statement somewhere in your code. As soon as the js engine reads that command, a break point is set and the debugger is loaded.

You might want to give that a shot. It might still not work correctly since dynamic script insertion can still be trouble and pain, depending how and when you do it.

It would definately a better idea to do it more "accurate" by creating and inserting a new `script element`

```
var myscript = document.createElement('script');
myscript.textContent = 'var scripts = 42; alert("hello");';
myscript.type = 'text/javascript';

document.body.appendChild(myscript);
```

Comment: The debugger; is a good chance. Anyway I move all JS to .js files to solve it :)